# Using _beginthreadex/_endthreadex functions

Tags: c++, winapi

I checked the source code of a project with an analyzer. I am new to C++.

It tells me that I should use Use _beginthreadex/_endthreadex functions instead of CreateThread/ExitThread functions

```
std::unique_ptr<Thread> Thread::Create(CreationParameters params,
                                   std::function<void()> start_routine) {
auto start_data = new ThreadStartData({std::move(start_routine)});
HANDLE handle =
  CreateThread(NULL, params.stack_size, ThreadStartRoutine, start_data,
               params.create_suspended ? CREATE_SUSPENDED : 0, NULL);
if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

void Thread::Exit(int exit_code) { ExitThread(exit_code); }
```

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise (which is pretty doubtful), use `std::thread` and be done with it.

Comment: @Harry you answered my question thanks

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I guess I'll take your word for that--I haven't used `CreateThread` or `_beginthread` for quite a while now since `std::thread` is generally sufficient for my needs (and if it isn't, my next stop is generally Boost `thread`).

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I'm pretty sure the advice is still true. The old reason no longer is (leaking memory when calling the CRT on a thread created using `CreateThread`). There's a different reason, though: The CRT terminating a process under low-memory conditions, when calling into the CRT on a thread created using `CreateThread`.

Comment: @IInspectable, I'm not sure, but I think that is still true.  It's an edge case, though; it only matters if you are trying to write code that is robust under low-memory conditions, and that's so difficult to do that pretty much nobody ever bothers.  (I'm not sure it is even possible; for example, what happens when the stack needs to expand and there's no memory left?)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Do you have a source for these thread pool claims? And when was it fixed, after VC6 I assume? And what if you link statically and have no DllMain notification? TLS callback?

Comment: @Anders, well, the thread pool is part of the Win32 API so it *can't* have a dependency on the CRT; it is available for all code, not just C code.  Yes, IIRC the thread leak was resolved in the static case by using a TLS callback.  I don't remember exactly when, a long time ago.  Hans or Cody might know.

Comment: Typo correction: "thread leak" -> "memory leak"

Comment: @Anders, FWIW, I've just checked Visual Studio 6 and it already has the memory leak fix for the case where the CRT is linked dynamically.  The static case couldn't be resolved until Windows Vista added the FlsAlloc function, so probably VC++ 2008 or 2010.  The more serious problems were resolved much earlier: if I'm reading [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/104641/description-of-using-c-run-time-crt-functions-and-createthread) correctly, then both Visual C++ 2.0 and the 32-bit version of 1.0 were already OK apart from the small memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you are doing. If you are only calling Windows API functions in the new thread then `CreateThread` is fine but if you are calling C standard library functions in the thread then you are supposed to use `_beginthreadex`. `_beginthreadex` will call `CreateThread` internally but it might also allocate and initialize some per-thread CRT state.

I see someone in the comments claiming that the CRT no longer assigns CRT state this way. I don't know if that's true and either way, it is a implementation detail and could change depending on the compiler version. `_beginthreadex` will never be wrong so there is no reason not to use it.

Comment: In practice, such a change would be *extremely* unlikely, because it would break existing code and make it impossible to use the thread pool.  But there's nothing wrong with defensive programming, where possible.  (The main problem with the advice to always use `_beginthreadex` is just that it unnecessarily frightens people away from using the thread pool.  Not applicable in this case.  +1.)